# Compiling/Building Google App Engine Java Project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications, vs-web-application-project

Good day everyone!

I am a graduating student doing Google App Engine-Java Web Application.

My problem is I need to compile/build it so it will run upon click. I've been trying exporting it to a jar file however it outputs no main class.... problem.

I've been looking for other method but internet fails me or maybe i'm not pointing on the right track.

Here's my output whenever I'm using the command line:

[image: command line]

its working fine when i'm using eclipse.

Any leads? Sorry if my question is quite silly.

Thanks in advance :))

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are you trying to build/compile? Are you trying to install the Java SDK? You can find instructions for doing so here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/installing

Comment: I'm trying to run my project without the use of any IDE. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should definitely consider updating your GAE SDK as it seems the defaultZoneTL field was removed from JDK 1.6 U31.  Updating the GAE SDK should avoid that problem.

If you can't do that then check http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6928 and try to implement one of the workarounds suggested.  (Essentially launching with -Dappengine.user.timezone.impl=UTC OR -Dappengine.user.timezone=UTC)

Comment: Thank you, I finally solved it. Many many many thanks everyone :))

Comment: @Rodel Glad it works - Maybe you can accept the answer or suggest edits?